# Array and HashMap Notation in Codecademy

Tags: java

I was on Codecademy learning the Java course, and I came across the Arrays. The notation is interesting

```
ArrayList<Integer> weeklyTemperatures = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        weeklyTemperatures.add(78);
```

I have never seen the arrow notation (<>) and furthermore, I've only heard about Arrays and not ArrayLists, along with seeing only bracket notation for Arrays[].
The same goes for Hashmap. Upon looking each up, I only found object declarations without the arrow notation.

What exactly is the arrow notation? Did it get replaced?

Comment: It is called Generics.

Comment: "Upon looking each up, I only found object declarations without the arrow notation" - really? I can understand not finding the "generics" name, but Googling "ArrayList" or "HashMap" turns up tons of results with the `<>` signs.

Comment: Arrays have a fixed length when they get created, so if you don't know how many elements you are going to have, you're probably not going to use an array. What an ArrayList does is essentially to create a new array every time you add something to it with one more length and copy everything from the previous array into the new one as far as I am aware.

Comment: @Gendarme: It grows the array by a multiplicative factor and keeps track of the logical size of the ArrayList separately from the physical size of the array, to maintain amortized constant time appends instead of ridiculously expensive linear-time appends.

Comment: @user2357112 Are you saying that it creates arrays of sizes a, b, c, d, ...(the smallest one which is large enough to contain all elements) and only creates a new array if you reach any of these limits (for example going from a-1 to b)?

Comment: @Gendarme: There's no fixed list of appropriate sizes, but if you run out of space and try to add another element, it's going to allocate room for a number of extra elements proportional to the old size of the array.

Comment: You will find the documentation on ArrayList [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow notation implies generics. This means that an `ArrayList` is going to be created, that contains items of the object within the <>. So using your example,

```
ArrayList<Integer> weeklyTemperatures = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This is declaring a new `ArrayList` that contains the Object type `Integer`. Using generics, you cannot use primitive types unlike you can in arrays, such as `int` or `float`. You have to use the corresponding object type such as `Integer` or `Float`.

`ArrayList` is similar to arrays, but they have a more dynamic size. This is an advantage when you don't know how big an array is going to be.

Accessing data in the ArrayList can be done using an enhanced for loop for easier readability. This can be done in Java 5 or later. The syntax is as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> weeklyTemperatures = new ArrayList<Integer>();
weeklyTemperatures.add(78); //add some values in here.
weeklyTemperatures.add(90);

for( Integer temperature : weeklyTemperatures ) {
    System.out.println( "Temp is: " + temperature ); //do whatever with each temp here.
}
```